# Mount Windows share as guest from command line

Tags: networking, mount, cifs

So I'm at a friend and hooked up my external EXT4 HDD to his router and it recognises it and he can connect his entire family to it and everything works fine.

*However*, on my Ubuntu machine *I can*:

- Go to my File Manager (Nemo)
- <kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Connect to Server</kbd>

[image: Connection dialog]

*and that works fine!*

#### but I cannot:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 /media/MichelNAS/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'

sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 /media/MichelNAS/
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4: 

sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 /media/MichelNAS/
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 -o user=,password= /media/MichelNAS/ 
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,noperm,sec=none //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 /media/MichelNAS/
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

**However:**

```
smbclient --list=192.168.1.1 --no-pass
```

works perfectly and has as output:

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.24]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (mymodem Sharing Files)
    Fab-EXT4        Disk      Share Fab-EXT4 directory
Domain=[HOME] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.24]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    MYMODEM              mymodem Sharing Files

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    HOME
```

So I'm obviously missing something *completely stupid here*, but I'm stumped as to ***why I cannot mount this share from the command line???***

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add the version to the options depending on the cifs version you use. So that would be for v1.0:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,guest,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/Fab-EXT4 /media/MichelNAS/
```

There is also `vers=2.0` and `vers=3.0`

Comment: Seemingly very old Modem firmware! `vers=1.0` seemed to do the trick!

Comment: found this answer out of the blue worked for an upgrade in pop os from 21.10 to 22.04. fstab entry was just `guest` and it failed to mount at all after upgrading. adding `guest,vers=3.0` solved it

Comment: @JeffPuckett cool aAd to anyone else: do not still use v1.0 please :D